# CLion infinitely building symbols

Tags: clion

When I start CLion, it loads an existing project by itself. It infinitely builds symbols to update indices. It does that even if I stop loading a project. Every time I open a project it infinitely build symbols. I could not find a way to stop the building symbols. After few minutes the whole CLion disappears and I have to start it again and it does the same thing over and over again. Is there a way to stop this? I am using CLion 1.0.1 . Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be due to insufficient memory. Try increasing the amount of memory available to the process by modifying the `-Xmx` setting in the vmoptions file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but in my case I had run out of disk space on the virtual machine. Cleaning up disk space made the symbols loading finish immediately.